# What's the best way to evaluate a PHP short open tag in echo file_get_contents()?

Tags: php, html

I have a snippet of html containing some php short tags that I am returning via file_get_contents(). The problem with this is that PHP returns the short open tags inside of the document without parsing them as php. What is the best way to go about getting returned html to evaluate the php inside of it?

I have tried 
`echo eval('?>'.file_get_contents('/path/to/file.html'));`

and this works, but php docs discourage the use of eval for obvious reasons.

Comment: You could activate `php_short_tags` in the php.ini. Also if you want the file to be parsed you need to include it. `file_get_contents` gets like it says the content and with `echo` you're just printing it to the browser.

Comment: 1) Don't use short tags (i.e go in a manually edit them to standard tags), 2) use `$page = include('/path/to/file.html'); echo $page;`

Comment: Including the file seems to work as I'd want it done, but why eliminate short tags? It still seems to work fine leaving the short tags in.